# En ExtJs, como puedo cambiar las propiedades de un objeto después de que este fue creado?

Tags: extjs

Tengo un objeto de tipo **textfield**, quiero cambiarle varias propiedades en el vuelo dependiendo del valor de otro campo. Existe alguna función para hacer esto? 
Las propiedades que quiero cambiar son

**allowBlank**  ---> false|true

**hidden**      ---> false|true

con el **hidden** no tengo problemas, utilizo el método setHidden(true|false), es para el **allowBlank** que no he encontrado un método.

¿Alguna solución ?

PD: Si no expliqué bien mi problema pueden pedir mas detalles, no adjunté el código porque no creo que sea necesario, si lo necesitan lo escribo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar la propiedad de una configuración puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
Ext.apply(**Componente**, {
        allowBlank: true
    });
```

Donde **Componente** es al cual le quieres aplicar la nueva configuracion, saludos.

Comment: Es justo lo que buscaba, gracias por tu respuesta erick, no esperaba que fuera tan rápido